# MySql left join вывод пользоватлей

Tags: mysql

Как вывести пользователей, которых нет во второй таблице?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(users.id), users.* FROM users
left JOIN operator_to_checkings on operator_to_checkings.operator_id != users.id
where users.domain_id = 1 and users.role_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
WHERE users.domain_id = 1 
  AND users.role_id = 3
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM operator_to_checkings 
                   WHERE operator_to_checkings.operator_id = users.id )
```

Comment: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'AMD NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM operator_to_checkings
  ' на строке 5

Comment: проверочка)))))))